# transforming number to month name in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

there is a column of mixed factor values ['August', 'September', '1', '12', 'December']. How to transform values '1', '2' into 'January' and 'February', without hard-coding them?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a tidyverse solution, I recommend `recode()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

month_key <- deframe(tibble(X = 1:12, Y = month.name))

mutate(df, month = recode(month, !!!month_key))

# # A tibble: 5 × 1
#   month  
#   <chr>  
# 1 April  
# 2 August 
# 3 January
# 4 March  
# 5 January
```

Data

```
df <- tibble(month = c("April", "August", "1", "3", "January"))
```

Comment: `month_key` can be simplified to `deframe(tibble(X = 1:12, Y = month.name))`

Comment: @CasparV.: A no regrets option. Obvious (in hindsight). Edit made. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
df$month <- ifelse(df$month %in% month.name , df$month ,
 month.name[as.numeric(df$month)])
```

- Data

```
df <- data.frame(month = c('August', 'September', '1', '12', 'December'))
```

- Output

```
      month
1    August
2 September
3   January
4  December
5  December
```

If the Warning message annoying you

```
df$month <- lapply(df$month , \(x) if(x %in% month.name) x else month.name[as.numeric(x)]) |> unlist()
```